# Oracle joining tables where the matching process starts after certain digits

Tags: oracle, join, match, digits

I have joined two tables which contain words as well as values. The matching of the words works. The matching of the values do not. The reason is that the values in the table "GATTUNGSDATEN" always start with 4 zeros whereas in the table BONDMAPPING not. E.g. 00001234 = 1234. What query could I use in order to have the matching process started after 4 digits?

```
select MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN.ranl, MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN.vvranlwx, 
V_AR_BONDMAPPING.MUREXEXTERNALID

from V_AR_BONDMAPPING

RIGHT JOIN MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN

ON V_AR_BONDMAPPING.MUREXEXTERNALID = MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN.ranl IN 
('%%%%')

where vvranlwi=34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always four leading zeroes you can use SUBSTR():

```
from V_AR_BONDMAPPING
RIGHT JOIN MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN
    ON V_AR_BONDMAPPING.MUREXEXTERNALID =  substr(MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN.ranl, 5)
```

This trims the leading four characters from `MET_SEC_INDEX_GATTUNGSDATEN.ranl`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of the identifiers you could pad the shorter identifier with leading zeroes

```
select lpad(1234, 8, '0') from dual
=>
00001234

select lpad('00001234', 8, '0') from dual
=>
00001234
```

This will implicitly convert the numbers into VARCHAR2s however, which on the other hand is what would happen anyways during the comparison